# How to select parent div contents

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the image inside parent div's sideblings with Jquery. I wonder what's the best and fast way to find it.

```
html

more divs..and all generated dynamically..
<div>
other dynamically generated image...

<img src='haha1.jpg' />
<img src='haha2.jpg' />
</div>

<div>div 2</div>
<div>div 3</div>
<div>div 4</div>
<div>div 5</div>

more divs....

<div>
<button id='btn'/>
</div>


$('#btn').click(function(){

   //I have to change image source by using parent() method....

})
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: ...change the `href` of what image exactly, you have 2(and more) in there

Comment: and... can't you simply add an `id` or `class` to the DIV that holds the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your button can have an `ID`...

```
<div id="images">  <!-- add an ID here too -->
   <img src='haha1.jpg' />
   <img src='haha2.jpg' />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var source = 'folder_name/';

$('#btn').click(function(){
   $('#images').find('img').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('src', source+this.src);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to change the src of an image inside a particular div.  If that is the case, see if the options in this code can help.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

//I have to change image source by using parent() method....


$("#divId").children("img").attr("src", "newImgSource.jpg"); //this will probably  change all the images int the div.
$("#imgId").attr("src", "newImgSource.jpg");//this should change a specific image's src.


});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/truuD/12/

I usually use .prev() and .find() for things like this. Not sure if its the fastest or best way but it works for me.

```
$("button").click(function(){               
    console.log($(this).parent("div").prev("div").find("img"));
});​
```

Comment: Or i guess you can just go:
    $(this).parent("div").find("div img")